# why my program will not return to the missing variable box when an unhandled exception comes up in C#

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

When I run the program I intentionally leave one of the variables empty so I can get the `MessageBox.Show();` stating that you can't forget any variables or the program will not calculate the result of the final output.

But when I click ok the app still calculates the results (which is wrong because there is a variable missing).

I used the `TBPRECIO.Focus();` to get back to the missing variable but it still finishes without it.

```
private void ENTRADAS()
{
    try
    {
        PRECIO = Convert.ToDouble(TBPRECIO.Text);
        CANTIDAD = Convert.ToDouble(TBCANTIDAD.Text);
        CATEGORIA = Convert.ToDouble(TBCATEGORIA.Text);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("there cannot be any empty variable");
        TBPRECIO.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to give an answer, but because you catch the error, the code will carry on with the lines that come after the `catch` block. If you want it to stop there, you need to manually stop.

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble` returns 0 (zero) if the value is null, or in your case an empty string.

Comment: @MattU - I was under the same impression, but I just ran a test and `Convert.ToDouble` is throwing on `null`, `""`, or `"X"`.

Comment: @Enigmatiy haha, now u realize it ToDouble actually throws on string.Empty.
And that's why the messagebox is also displayed. You simply didn't understand the whole subject. Better don't correct other users if the problem is on your side.

Comment: Strange, the documentation doesn't say that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDouble_System_String_

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an if-else statement?

```
      if(TBPRECIO.Text==""||TBCANTIDAD.Text==""||TBCATEGORIA.Text){ 
    MessageBox.Show("there cannot be any empty variable");
                TBPRECIO.Focus();
     
    }
     else{
     //Your Condition
    }
```

Comment: The question is more about why an exception doesn't occur, not how to avoid it.

Comment: The exception occurs and also the messagebox. He writes that when he clicks "OK" (i.e. the OK button of the messagebox that is displayed in catch) then the calculation isn't stopped.

Comment: Exactly, THAT IS MY POINT. I don't want the program to keep calculating if a variable is missing. Because the final result will depend on the "CATEGORIA" variable. Like if it is CATEGORIA (category in English) 2, or 3, or 4, the program will determine the percentage that will be discounted from the final result.

Comment: Code above is just to determine if your variable is empty or missing input. If the statement is true, it will show that "there cannot be any empty variable." And if the variable is not empty, it will execute your input condition.

Answer (score 1):

System.Convert.ToDouble will succeed if the value is null but will fail if it is an empty string.  Form controls with a Text property (whether winform or webform) never return null.

If your objects aren’t controls you might be getting a null value instead of an empty string.  Regardless, your error message is too generic, and is in fact misleading.

```cs
const msgSuffix = “ cannot be empty and must be a number”
double pr =0, cd=0, ca=0;
if ((!double.TryParse(TBPRECIO.Text, out pr)) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TBPRECIO.Text)) {
     MessageBox.Show($"TBPRECIO{msgSuffix}");
     TBPRECIO.Focus();
}
else if ((!double.TryParse(TBCANTIDAD.Text, out cd)) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TBCANTIDAD.Text))
   {
     MessageBox.Show($"TBCANTIDAD{msgSuffix}");
     TBCANTIDAD.Focus();
}
else if((!double.TryParse(TBCATEGORIA.Text, out ca)) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TBCATEGORIA.Text))){
     MessageBox.Show($"TBCATEGORIA{msgSuffix}");
     TBCATEGORIA.Focus();
}
else {
    PRECIO = pr;
    CANTIDAD = cd;
    CATEGORIA = ca;
}
```

Now, you get an error message that refers to the right field AND accurately describes the situation, making it a lot more effective.

Comment: Alright I will look into this one and try to implement it. Thanks a lot